# Firebase Android getting URL from storage

Tags: android, url, firebase, firebase-storage

Need a help with getting URL of images which stored in Firebase Storage.
I uploaded via Firebase console image and trying to get URL and then show it via Picasso. What I tried:

```
 StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://My link com"); 
     storageRef.child("Images/Team.jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(Team.this, new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            teamImage.setText(uri.toString());
       Picasso.with(TeamList.this).load(uri.toString()).into(imageView);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            teamImage.setText("FALSE");
        }
    });
```

It shows always `FALSE`
What I am doing wrong?

In Swift possible use:

```
              FIRStorage.storage().referenceWithPath
```

and connect it to `imageView`. Is it possible same in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: inside `onFailure` add `exception.printStackTrace();` and cause of issue will appear in logcat

Comment: also, take a look at firebase ui examples, it uses glide to handle caching and show https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage

Comment: Thank you very much, firebase ui work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> connect it to imageView. Is it possible same in java?

Yes, it's possible. Firebase UI has [great example](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage) which you can use. It includes caching and displaying images.

Answer (score 0):

use this code snippet:
`Picasso.with(TeamList.this).load(uri).into(imageView);`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Folks here are excited and grateful to learn from you but it's important to help them understand you. Consider using [backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for code sections, it increases readability. For example `41 + 1 = 42` is easier to read than 41 + 1 = 42. Again welcome and good skills moving forward :)